# How to convert code decimal value in php

Tags: php, decimal

I have string with `Code Decimal` and want convert like this:

Current sting:

```
24&#8423; Guage Rake;
```

And want to convert like this:

```
24" Guage Rake
```

I have tried with this but not getting proper result:

```
$string = "hello&#8423";
htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: &#84 is to encode the char 'T', the right ISO encoding for the char '"' is &#34; i think that you have to check your used encoding function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars_decode()` only changes a few characters like quotation marks.

You need to use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead. Also, `"hello&#8423"` is missing a semicolon. Should be <s>`"hello&#8423;"`</s> `"hello&#8243;"`.

Try this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF8");
$string = "hello&#8243;";
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
echo $string;
```

Comment: you forgot the semicolon :) ironic... damn copy-paste `$string = "hello&#8423;";`

Comment: @AresDraguna Ooops :-)

Comment: I have check your code again and it prints `helloâƒ§`

Comment: @Mr.Happy Ah, yes. The character code was also wrong. Should be 8243, not 8423.

Comment: There is no need for `ENT_NOQUOTES`. It is working without `ENT_NOQUOTES` Just use `UTF-8` as charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead:

```
<?php
$string = '24 - your entity: ->  &#8243; <- -  Guage Rake;';
$decoded = html_entity_decode($string);
echo "$decoded\n";
```

Comment: Getting wrong result: `24 - your entity: -> âƒ§ <- - Guage Rake;`

Comment: @Mr.Happy As stated in other comment, the code should be `&#8243;`